# I want to use a class rule in my kv file at the top of a rule and this doesn't show me anything

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have an issue with an kv file and can't solve it. In the app, I use different screens and every screen should have the same menu bar. The app is provided for Android, but in the future I want to use it on Windows too. For Android, the menu bar should be at the bottom of the screen. For Windows, I want to place the menu bar at the top of the screens and there is my issue: the menu bar at the top doesn't work.

I've created a simple example code, to reproduce the issue.

Here is the a simple Python code. There is only one function to switch the screens:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MenuBar( Button ):
    pass

class Screen1( Screen ):
    pass

class Screen2( Screen ):
    pass

class ScreenManager( ScreenManager ):
    pass

class TestscreenApp( App ):
    def switch_screen( self, screen ):
        self.root.current = screen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestscreenApp().run()
```

And here is the kv file. There are 2 screens and a menu bar. I want to reuse the menu bar on different screens.

As you can see, the menu bar on the first screen is on the bottom of the screen. On the second screen, I placed the menu bar at the top and nothing will be displayed :-(

If I place the menu bar on the second screen at the bottom, it works. If I place the menu bar on the first screen at the top, this also display me nothing.

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager

    Screen1:
        name: "screen_1"
        screen_manager: "screen_manager"
    Screen2:
        name: "screen_2"
        screen_manager: "screen_manager"

<Screen1>:
    name: "screen_1"
    
    GridLayout:
        rows:           2

        GridLayout:
            cols:       2
            
            Button:
                text: 'Test 1'
                font_size: 50
                    
            Button:
                text: 'Test 2'
                font_size: 50

        MenuBar:

<Screen2>:
    name: "screen_2"

    GridLayout:
        rows:           2

        MenuBar:
        
        Button:
            text: 'Test 3'
            font_size: 50

            on_release:
                app.switch_screen( "screen_1" )
    
<MenuBar>:
    name: "menu_bar_top"
    
    GridLayout:
        cols:   2
        size: root.width, root.height
        
        Button:
            text: 'Menu 1'
            font_size: 20

            on_release:
                app.switch_screen( "screen_1" )
                
        Button:
            text: 'Menu 2'
            font_size: 20

            on_release:
                app.switch_screen( "screen_2" )
```

I tried many things and used the search, but I can't find anything similar. I also tried to use BoxLayout instead of GridLayout, but I can't find a solution.

What I am doing wrong? Can anyone explain me this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are defining the `MenuBar` as extending `Button`, then using it as a widget container. A `Button` is not intended to be used as a container. A better choice would be one of the `Layout` classes. Try changing:

```
class MenuBar( Button ):
    pass
```

to:

```
class MenuBar( RelativeLayout ):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You made my day! That is a solution for my problem.

I did not think to change my Python code. All the time I've changed my kv file to fix the issue.

Thanks